# cant get current user with axios get

Tags: axios, passport.js

In my API is the current user (I have logged in with passport) but when I make an Axios get request the data field is empty. I absolutely don't know what to do :(

```
<script>
import axios from "axios"

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      user: axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/').then(response => this.user = response)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

Here is my API:

[image: api]

Edit: Here is my Backend File:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const passport = require('passport')
let LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const session = require('express-session')

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const port = 3000

app.use(cors({
  methods:['GET','POST'],
  credentials: true 
}))

app.use(express.static('public'))

//Passport setup

app.use(session({
  secret: 'test',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secure: true
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});


const apiRoutes = require('./apiRoutes')
app.use(cors())



app.use('/api', apiRoutes)

// connect to database
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://@cluster0.dhsiv.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, () => {
    console.log('Erfolgreich connected')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server is running on port '+port)
})

module.exports;
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot guys :)
i have also change my data and run the axios get in mounted but it doesnt change anything.

Routes:

```
const { _ } = require('core-js');
const { Mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const { find, where } = require('./models/userModel');
const userModel = require('./models/userModel');
let router = require('express').Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { static } = require('express');
require('./passportConfig')


router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
      user: req.user
    });
});
```

Comment: why did you put api call with axios in `data`? create a method for it or put it in `mounted()`

Comment: @tao sry for that. I tought maybe this could help. I am totally new in JS developement :( i cant understand why i cant get the data. Can it be that i need a token or something like that? is it for secure that i cant get the data? I have really no idea what i can do

Comment: @functionPublic, kusiaga is right. I just noticed it. Put an empty string in `data.user` and call the API from `mounted()` and replace `this.user` with the response:
`data: () => ({ user: ''}), mounted() { axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/').then(response => this.user = response); }`. I haven't spotted it before. You shouldn't place functions in `data`. `data` is an object or a function returning an object with all the reactive properties you want on your component.

Comment: As for why your backend doesn't return the data you expect, you haven't showed anything remotely related to what's behind `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api`. Technically, it's impossible for anyone to know until you actually give us enough detail on why you're expecting anything other than an empty response from there.

Comment: ok i will edit my post. Sry that iam so unprofessionally. I dont have many experience.